# How to fulfil two conditions in ifelse function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have two columns one is gender and the other one a measure as below. I want to set cutoffs for male(gender = 1) and measure column. I want to say if it is male and measure is less that 23 then it is 1 otherwise 0 and if if it is female and measure is less that 15 then it is 1 otherwise 0.
I tried below, but not not working. I appreciate your help.

```
d$measure_status = ifelse(d$gender ==2 & d$measure<15, 1, ifelse( d$gender ==1 & d$measure<23, 1), 0) 



gender  measure   measure_status
2       14           
2       17
1       25
1       26
```

Comment: I think this is just a typo, the second to last `)` should be moved all the way to the right. So `ifelse(..., 1, ifelse(..., 1, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with` and make it a single ifelse condition

```
df = data.frame(gender = c(2,2,1,1), measure = c(14,17,25,26))
df$measure_status <- with(df, ifelse((df$gender ==2 & df$measure<15) | (df$gender ==1 & df$measure<23), 1 , 0))
df
```

Output:

```
  gender measure measure_status
1      2      14              1
2      2      17              0
3      1      25              0
4      1      26              0
```

You can also use `transform`

```
df = data.frame(gender = c(2,2,1,1), measure = c(14,17,25,26))
df <- transform(df, measure_status = ifelse((df$gender ==2 & df$measure<15) | (df$gender ==1 & df$measure<23), 1 , 0))
```